# PhpStorm debug HTTP request not hitting breakpoint

Tags: phpstorm

I am fairly certain that I have PhpStorm configured correctly for debugging. When I create a run configuration as "PHP Script", the debugger functions as expected.

Now, I want to debug an "HTTP request" as described in [the official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-a-php-http-request.html), because I want to pass some `$_GET` parameters - note, this is an AJAX request from the browser.

However, despite following it, the debugger hits no breakpoints; not even on the first code line  - even when I set the "stop on first line" option.

[image]

When I click the URL indicated by the red arrow, it is launched in the browser (without the parameters), so the path looks ok. I see no PHP errors or warnings in the IDE, nor when I launch teh page int he browser.

vlocalhost` is running just fine.

Any idea what I am doing wrongly?

---

[Update] With thanks to @LazyOne for that comment.

File/Settings ... Languages & Frameworks/PHP/Debug, point 1), click the "validate" link.

The path shown was the path to the script, which is not the root of `localhost`. Changing it to the root of `localhost` validated and is valid - but I still don't hit any breakpoints :-(

[image]

Comment: Double check Xdebug config -- it can be different for CLI and web. Collect xdebug log -- see if t even tries to connect to IDE. If not, you or IDE may be not passing "debug me" flag etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @LazyOne for that comment.

File/Settings ... Languages & Frameworks/PHP/Debug, point 2), seems to have fixed it, installing the browser plugin from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/browser-debugging-extensions.html and activating it (point 3 might also have helped; try it if point 2 isn't enough for you)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might help some using Windows.

Go to `File > Settings > PHP > Servers` and uncheck '`use path mappings...`'